# Why is the digest algorithm specified in two places in CMS / PKCS7?

Tags: asn1, pkcs7

In [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.3), *Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)*, section *5.3. SignerInfo Type*, there's a `digestAlgorithm` field that has values like `id-sha256`, `id-sha1`, etc.

In that same RFC, section *[5.1. SignedData Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.1)* there's a `digestAlgorithms` field that in my testing generally has as many entries in it as there are `SignerInfo`'s.

My question is...  why is the `digestAlgorithm` field being specified in two places? It seems unnecessarily redundant.

Answer (score 2):

As 5.1 says (redacted and emphasis added):

> digestAlgorithms ... is intended to list the
>         message digest algorithms employed by all of the signers, in any
>         order, to **facilitate one-pass signature verification.**
>         Implementations MAY fail to validate signatures that use a digest
>         algorithm that is not included in this set.  ...

In other words, a receiver/verifier can start from the beginning of the message and:

1. read `digestAlgorithms` and set up contexts for those algorithms
2. read `encapContentInfo` and run the data, which can be quite large depending on the digest(s) e.g. 2^64 for SHA-1, through the digest algorithm, or algorithms in parallel, and at the same time also store and/or process and/or relay the data as desired; or if "detached" obtain the data from somewhere else and similarly run it through the digest(s) and maybe other use.
3. read `certificates` and `crls` if present and keep them handy if desired and not too large and not duplicating data already available locally; can discard them if desired, conditional on being able to re-fetch them if and when needed using things like LDAP or AIA (including OCSP)
4. read `signerInfos` and for each one (of interest) select the correct already-computed digest and use it, plus the `signedAttrs` if used, to verify the `signature`, without going back to the data

Although not so clearly stated, this is also the reason *many* (not all!) structures in CMS are specified as BER, which can at the sender's choice use indefinite-length encoding, instead of DER, which cannot.